# How would I get all people, that are following my in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am using the act_as_follower gem, and I get all the users, that I follow, but now I want all the users, that are following me, how would I do that. I checked and I think something like this
current_user.followers, but I cant get it working. My code for people that I am following is this:

```
<% @users = User.all %>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <% unless user == current_user %>
        <div class="container people-lists list-following">
            <%= image_tag("/assets/" +  user.avatar + ".png",  alt: "Logo", class: "people-image") %>
            <%= user.username %>
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
                <% unless user == current_user %>
                    <% if current_user.following?(user) %>
                        <%= button_to("Un-Follow", user_follow_path(user.to_param, current_user.get_follow(user).id), :method => :delete, :remote => true, class: 'btn btn-primary button') %>
                    <% else %>
                        <%= button_to("Follow", user_follows_path(user.to_param), :remote => true, class: 'btn btn-primary button') %>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I the User.all returns all of them, and I can use the all_following, and follows like this and it works.

```
<% @users = current_user.all_following %>
```

And like this

```
<% @users = current_user.followers %>
```